# Linux create user template

Tags: linux, bash

I wondered if it was possible to make a template which i can execute, to create users with my input. I was thinking something along the lines of:

Username: test1 (input)

Password: test123 (input)

**And** decide home folder and group permissions.
Maybe my understanding is totally off, but it would simplify a lot. Hope someone can help.

Comment: Do you just want to avoid the "useradd" command? If yes, why do not you write a script which accepts the desired args? The script can infact read from a file the details of multiple users and create the new users.

Comment: Hey Jose, thanks for commenting. Basically nothing.. Its just that soon i have to make a lot of users and assign them to groups. And all i got is the basics `sudo useradd test2 -d /testusr_homedrive/test2 -m -g Syd`

Comment: @TechEnthusiast thanks for commenting, i want to avoid too much "slave labor" and just ./useradd_temp or something and then fill in the users data. but i have no idea how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a simple example, you probably should check if input is valid.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Username: "
read username

echo -n "Password: "
read password

sudo useradd ${username} -d /testusr_homedrive/${username} -p ${password} -m -g Syd
```

Then `chmod +x <script file>` and copy to `/usr/bin/` so you can run it directly from anywhere.

Comment: This looks good, but i cant add permissions and home dir into this?

Comment: What permissions? Home dir is the `-d /testusr_homedrive/${username}`

Comment: I confused permissions on folder and group level with user permissions to rwx. if that makes sense. I appreciate the script a lot! just 1 more question. I want my users to have **no** access to anything else than their home folder and group folder. So my thought is a group in a group. is that possible?

Comment: Looks like you want something like a jail chroot, read: http://askubuntu.com/questions/93411/simple-easy-way-to-jail-users (there are a lot of topics that explains how to do it), then just add the extra commands to the script.